# Conflicting solutions in linear programming in MATLAB and Python

Tags: python, matlab, optimization, linear-programming, cvxopt

I am trying to run a large-scale linear program and am translating some of my previous code from MATLAB into Python.  However, the problem is that MATLAB and Python are giving me drastically conflicting answers: the MATLAB code finds the optimal solution, yet the Python code says that the problem is infeasible.  This is an LP modelling of ell_infinity regression or minimax regression.  I am fairly confident in the setup of both functions.

MATLAB code:

```
function [ x_opt, f_opt, exitflag, output] = ell_infinity_reg_solver( A, b )
% Solves the ell_infinity regression problem ||Ax - b||_inf.  That is finds
% the least t for which Ax - b < t.ones and Ax - b > -t.ones.
[n,d] = size(A) ;  
if n == 0
    f_opt  = 0 ;
    x_opt = zeros(d,1) ;
    return
end

% infinity norm
f = [ zeros(d,1); 1 ];
A = sparse([ A, -ones(n,1) ; -A, -ones(n,1) ]);
b = [ b; -b ];
[xt, f_opt, exitflag, output] = linprog(f,A,b);
x_opt = xt(1:d,:);


end
```

Python code

```
from scipy.optimize import linprog
import numpy as np


def ell_infinity_regression_solver(A, b):
    """Compute the solution to the ell_infinity regression problem.
    x_hat = arg min_x ||Ax - b||_infty by a reformulating as LP:

    min t :
    Ax - b <= t * ones
    b - Ax >= - t*ones

    i.e. finds minimal radius ball enclosing distance between all data points
    and target values b.

    Input:
    A - array or datafram of dimension n by d
    b - target vector of size n by 1.

    Output:
    x_opt which solves the optimisation.
    f_opt the radius of the enclosing ball
    """
    n,d = A.shape

    # include a check on n and d to ensure dimensionality makes sense

    if n > 0:
        f = np.vstack((np.zeros((d,1)), [1])).ravel()
        print("shape of f {}".format(f.shape)) # should be d+1 length
        big_A = np.hstack((np.vstack((A,-A)), np.ones((2*n,1))))
        print("shape of big_A {}".format(big_A.shape)) # should be 2n*(d+1)
        #big_b = np.vstack((b,-b)) # should be length 2n
        big_b = b.append(-b) # only works for data frames -- switch to np array?
        print("Type of b {}".format(type(b)))
        print("Shape of b {}".format(b.shape))
        print("shape of big_b {}".format(big_b.shape))
        output = linprog(f, A_ub=big_A, b_ub=big_b)
        #print(output)

    else:
        f_opt = 0
        x_opt = np.zeros_like(b)


    return output
```

As the `scipy` method didn't work wI also tried `CVXOPT` with the added lines

```
c = cvxopt.matrix(f)
G = cvxopt.matrix(X)
h = cvxopt.matrix(Y)
output = cvxopt.solvers.lp(c, G, h, solver='glpk')
```

But again this returned a flag of `dual-infeasible` which contrasts the MATLAB `exitflag=1` (success) and `dual-simplex` algorithm used.

The data I tested on is a 500 by 11 data matrix with an associated set of response variables.

I am interested in what has caused such a significant difference in the outputs and which of these is correct.  One thing which does add confusion is that reducing the size of the input to one which is less than full-rank doesn't seem to affect the MATLAB output flag but the Python code doesn't find an optimal solution (as expected I think).

The data is at https://www.dropbox.com/s/g4qcj1q0ncljawq/dataset.csv?dl=0 and the matrix A is the first 11 columns and the target vector is the final column.

Comment: If your problem is indeed large I recommend using an external solver (within `scipy`) such as mosek (https://www.mosek.com/), which was the only solver capable of producing a solution in reasonable time for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) Default variable bounds are almost always zero and infinity. I.e., most solvers assume non-negative variables unless otherwise stated. Matlab uses a different default. There by default variables are free.

For your model this means you will need to explicitly tell `linprog` that the `x` variables are free. The `t` variable can be either free or non-negative.

Thus

```
output = linprog(f, A_ub=big_A, b_ub=big_b, bounds=(None,None),method='interior-point' )
```

The model is a bit large for the simplex method (the Simplex implementation is somewhat of a toy algorithm). The new interior point method has no problem with it.

(2) The line

```
big_A = np.hstack((np.vstack((A,-A)), np.ones((2*n,1))))
```

should probably read

```
big_A = np.hstack((np.vstack((A,-A)), -np.ones((2*n,1))))
```

(3) Also note that your model

```
min t :
Ax - b <= t * ones
b - Ax >= - t*ones
```

is incorrect. It should be:

```
min t :
Ax - b <= t * ones
Ax - b >= - t*ones
```

This gives as LP input:

```
min t :
 Ax - t <= b
-Ax - t  <= -b
```

(There are also other formulations for this problem, some do not store A twice. See [[link](http://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2017/11/lp-and-chebyshev-regression.html)])

Comment: Thanks this was really helpful.  Do you know of any concrete applications of ell_infty regression? I have read the sources in your link and searched myself but have found this difficult to pin down.

Comment: @CharlieDickens See e.g. [Farebrother](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9783642362996). A variant is also very interesting: the least median of squares problem [link](http://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2017/11/integer-programming-and-least-median-of.html).

Comment: This makes for interesting reading, thanks.  One thing I don't quite understand is the difference between your link and the Farebrother text (specifically Chapter 6).  In your blog have written that choosing n = h  means that the LMS problem reduces to Chebyshev Regression - this makes sense. However, Farebrother C6 abstract says choose roughly half of the data, running L inf regression, and then doing something which doesn't seem clear yields a robust LMS estimate.  Do you know of an arggument to make this rigorous?

Comment: You can generate all possible h out of n combinations and run a chebishev regression on them. Then pick the best one. This is not feasible for anything but the smallest problems. So a heuristic is: just sample a lot of h out of n combinations and pick the best. The hope is to be close to optimal. I have shown a different way: let the MIP model select the optimal h out of n (basically combine Chebyshev with picking the h smallest into one optimization problem)..